# Issues with the Date object when try to use getYear() and getDay() method

Tags: javascript, node.js

I try to use the date object from NodeJS v14.15.1. And when I instantiate the object with the year, month and day parameter. When I try to use the getDay() and getYear() method, I don't have the right number.

I really don't know what going on and why this method don't return what's I expected.

```js
const date = new Date(2021, 4, 1) // I create a date object for 2021/04/01
console.log(date.getDay()) // This return 6 instead of 1
console.log(date.getYear()) // This return 121 instead if 2021
```

Comment: [RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#syntax)
`const date = new Date(2021, 3, 1); console.log(date.getDay()); console.log(date.getfullYear())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some unfortunate historical naming of methods here.  Check out [MDN's documentation for `Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

- [`getDay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) returns the day of the week (Sunday = 0, Monday = 1, etc.).  You probably want to use [`getDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) instead.
- Similarly, [`getYear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear) returns the year minus 1900.  You probably want to use [`getFullYear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear) instead.
- Although you didn't mention it, note that [`getMonth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) is zero-based: 0 = January, 1 = February, etc. The same is true for `new Date`. So `new Date(2021, 4, 1)` corresponds to the ISO date 2021-05-01.